# Split encrypted text within brackets in java

Tags: java, regex

I have encrypted text wraped with brackets, i'm trying to get only the text `[|kXS6k~R5I~Q5gHR&f3gzJ[X]` -->`|kXS6k~R5I~Q5gHR&f3gzJ[X`
Found this pattern `[\[\](){}]` , it works but split until first brackets or if there are parenthesesit will split the text untill them .
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this: "\[(.*?)\]". And don't forget to have the backslash escaped in your string otherwise it will give you error

**String string = "[AA{R7QHQ8onQ~QXR7UXQzM\e{J6Y]";**

```
String regex = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
String string = "[AA{R7QHQ8onQ~QXR7UXQzM\\e{J6Y]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: plz clarify .. where is the [] bracket in this input : AA{R7QHQ8onQ~QXR7UXQzM\e{J6Y

Comment: you need to escape  the backslash in java, otherwise the string is invalid so \e becomes \\e   then apply my updated regex ...